# How to add android library project in another android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I am trying to add a library project in another project but I am unable to add it.

I made e.g. `Project A` as a library project by going in to its properties and checking `isLibrary` checkbox. Then I tried to add this in `Project B` , by going into its properties , and by clicking `Add` button and selecting `Project A` as a library.

Then I clicked on `ok` , but when I try to use any class or reference of `Project A` , I get an error that it is not defined. I checked `Project B's` properties again , and there is no reference there of `Project A`, which I established earlier.

The reference is automatically disappearing. I need help in this.

**Edit** : Both Projects are in same workspace.

Comment: Make sure your both projects are in same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The porblem was read-only persmissions of files of `Project B`. I eliminated read-only permissions and it is working now. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Check this please for example Facebook SDK:

[image: set of dependencies]

[image: connection library]

and try to press `Apply` before press `Ok`

Comment: It is still not working ,I press `apply` and `ok` , properties window closes and when I open it again the reference disappears

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem myself. The solution for was based on the location of the library project.

It needs to be in your **workspace** directory, "next" to the Android project you're trying to connect to it.

Is this the case for you?

Comment: Are you updated with the latest versions of the Android SDK, Build Tools and ADT plugin?

Comment: Yes , in my workspace there is already a library project and a project which is connected with it , and it is working fine. This was done by someone else

Answer (score 0):

You can add project A to the "libraries" folder into project B and then you should be able to use references.Every time the library you are using should be into your main project folder and not in the same workspace.Try this out.

Comment: @Hammad checkout whether jar is created or not in bin folder of project A library?